# browser.WaitForAngularEnabled(true) hangs the browser until jasmine default time expires

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing

I am working on angular 4 test automation and using Protractor tool. After many video tutorials I concluded that there is no need of WAIT functions for synchronization while using protractor. When I use `browser.WaitForAngularEnabled(true)` it hangs the browser until jasmine default time expires and the test case fails. Attached is the spec.ts `beforAll()` block code. Can any one tell me whether my concept is false or true and if it is true then what is the issue?

```js
login = new LoginPage();
        addMemeber = new AddMemberClass();

        return new Promise((resolve)=>{
            login.navigateTo().then(()=>{
                login.getEmailInput().sendKeys('valid_email@gmail.com');
                login.getPasswordInput().sendKeys('123456');
                login.getLoginButton().click();
                console.log('here is protractor');                
              
                    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
                    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('organization').then(()=>{
                        console.log('Nave bar present');
                        resolve();
                    })
              

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your point is valid for not using Wait functions for synchronization in protractor. Looking at your code looks like you are moving from non-angular to angular application. In this case "`waitForAngularEnabled(true)`" the Protractor checks for `angular` variable when loading a new page,

> the Default Timeout is for 10 seconds

and if it is not found then throws an error like this:

```
Message:
_[31m    Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
```

To solve this at individual level add `page timeout` parameter in your `browser.get(address, timeout_in_millis)` and globally add below line in configuration file

> getPageTimeout: timeout_in_millis

To get more understanding of `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` refer this discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44073142/1976848

For timeouts in Protractor: [Protractor Timeouts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts)

let me know if this helps!!

Comment: Thanks. The angular variable wasn't found when i manually inspected the page. Thanks once again

Comment: Also the link mentioned cleared my concepts a bit more

Comment: @Gupta Now my both pages are angular. still the browser is paused and waiting for angular variables. Can you help me in this case

Comment: The script fails after jasmine.default time.. it says default jasmine time out

Comment: Addittionally.. there is an error like waiting for angular.. time expired... although the app is developed  purely in angular 4

Comment: Umm..If its an pure angular app then no need of using "waitForAngularEnabled(true)". And for time expired occurs in case of IE due to async script. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411262/1976848

Comment: I am using Chrome, the default browser for protractor, and expiry time is more than enough i.e. 15 mins. All the things mentioned in reference link are already there in my script

Comment: Can you please share an error stack trace and code snippet related to it, which gives some clearer idea of what you are facing and will come up with a proper solution.

Comment: I am sharing the error log **should check fields/button shown to user
      - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
          at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
          at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
          at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
          at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)**

Comment: Even if I increase the default jasmine time out up to 15 min, it still waits and after 15 mins it throws the same error